# Static Variable can not be set inside inner class

Tags: java, actionlistener, inner-classes

So I am having problem that I can not understand the reason why the static variable of other class set inside the inner class implementing the ActionListener is not visible in the main test file.

Below are the three files I am having problem with.The expected action of changing static variable flag in Verification class should terminate the program but it doesn't.

[InnerClassTest File(Main class file)](http://pastie.org/private/x7kmaq0jowloo2m7clivhg)

```
package innerClass;

public class InnerClassTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        TalkingClock clock = new TalkingClock(2000, true);
        clock.start();
        while(true)
        {
            if(Verification.flag == true)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (TalkingClock.flag == true)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

[TalkingClock File](http://pastie.org/private/aunrao5wio3f8kjkx3qoa)

```
package innerClass;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TalkingClock
{
   private int interval;
   private boolean beep;
   public static boolean flag = false;
   public TalkingClock(int interval, boolean beep)
   {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.beep = beep;
   }

   public void start()
   {
        ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
        Timer t = new Timer(interval, listener);
        t.start();
   }

   public class TimePrinter implements ActionListener
   {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Date now = new Date();
            System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + now);
            if (beep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            Verification.flag = true;
            flag = true;
        }
   }
}
```

[Verification Class File](http://pastie.org/private/ralr8ryxjnaatrttu63ghq#1)

```
package innerClass;

public class Verification
{
    public static int count = 0;
    public static boolean flag = false;
}
```

Comment: It's important that all relevant information for the question is in the question and not only in links. Please keep that code in the question.

Comment: Your code is multithreaded (via the `Timer`) and not properly synchronized.  There is no particular reason to expect that one thread will see any writes performed by the other.

Comment: Try making flag volatile.

Comment: And you don't require (Verification.flag == true). just (Verification.flag) is sufficient. It's already a Boolean value. You don't have to check whether a Boolean value is true or false. It's already true or false by definition.

Comment: @shmosel why we need flag to be volatile? And I guess reason for static flag in Verification class not to work is maybe multithreading as pointed out by John Bollinger

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did not know that Timer is multi-threaded.Thanks

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil `volatile` fixes the multithreading issues pointed out by @JohnBollinger.

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil, if your code were *not* multithreaded, then the main method could never observe a change to the static variable that it had not made itself.  But yes, a `Timer` is able to perform work outside the flow of control of the thread that starts it because it runs tasks in a separate thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am in confusion.I can get logic behind the first sentence but then change in static variable should have been reflected during runtime.But why it didn't?

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil, if the value of any given variable changes, that is because some thread has written a new value to it.  Therefore, if the thread running `main()` does not change the value of a given variable but expects to eventually see its value change, then that thread is thereby assuming that another thread will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of multithreading issues, not inner classes or static variables.

You are accessing/modifying `flag` from multiple different threads, but not telling the compiler that it needs to ensure that the value is being correctly updated to reflect changes on other threads.

From the [JLS section 8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4):

> The Java programming language allows threads to access shared variables (§17.1). As a rule, to ensure that shared variables are consistently and reliably updated, a thread should ensure that it has exclusive use of such variables by obtaining a lock that, conventionally, enforces mutual exclusion for those shared variables.
>
> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism, volatile fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.
>
> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable

Without that keyword, the JVM and compiler are free to make optimizations which don't allow for changes by other threads. Make `flag` `volatile` and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks very much for detailed answer